# Is C# Dictionary<string, List<string>>.GetObjectData() (serialization) Consistent?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I know Dictionaries don't store their key-value pairs in the order that they are added, but if I add the same key-value pairs (potentially in different orders) to two different Dictionaries and serialize the results, will the data on file be the same?

Edit: To clarify, I'm asking specifically about the output of GetObjectData(), not any particular serializer. Consider the following code:

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dict1 = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
string key11 = "key1";
string key12 = "key1";
string key21 = "key2";
string key22 = "key2";
List<string> values11 = new List(1);
List<string> values12 = new List(1);
List<string> values21 = new List(1);
List<string> values22 = new List(1);
values11.add("value1");
values12.add("value1");
values21.add("value2");
values22.add("value2");
dict1.add(key11, values11);
dict2.add(key22, values22);
dict1.add(key21, values21);
dict2.add(key12, values12);
```

Will dict1 and dict2 return the same thing for GetObjectData()? If not, why not?

Comment: post some code you wrote that everyone could help you much easier :)

Comment: Why/How do you rely on the data being the 'same' ?

Comment: Henk: I want to serialize the current dictionary, compare it to the "gold standard" serialization, and if they are the same take one path and if they differ take another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not it is would end up being an implementation detail that likely would not be guaranteed in future versions and/or alternate implementations; As such, I would recommend at the very least having a test written that verifies it and can run as part of your standard tests.  But if you are implementing a solution that absolutely depends on it, then it may be worth writing your own serializer...

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly not!  The `Dictionary` works by hashing, and there has to be some method of hash collision resolution. So let's say that the first time you go through the dictionary you add `key1` and `key2` in that order. `key1` ends up in the "normal" spot for keys that hash to that particular value. `key2` is stored "somewhere else" (dependent on the implementation).

Now change the order that you add keys. `key2` goes in the normal spot and `key1` goes "somewhere else."

You cannot make any assumptions about the order of the items in your dictionary.

Even if you could guarantee the order, that guarantee could be invalidated with the next change to the .NET Framework because the implementation of `string.GetHashCode` might change (it has in the past). That would completely change the order in which keys are stored in the dictionary's underlying data structures, so any saved data created by a previous version of the Framework would likely not agree with data you create when running with the new version.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on internal implementation details of the particular (version of the) Dictionary.

So in general, No.

There have been topics here  about using Serialization to determine Equality, it fails on several corner cases.

Comment: It doesn't say IDictionary, so I assume System.Collections.Generic.

Comment: @GregC: I made it broader. And there still is the version. Do you want the code you write now also run under 5.0?

Comment: I agree that it's a hack.  So, write tests to ensure all is well is the best approach.  Better yet, write it out to a list by traversing keys, then serialize.  But even then, there will be some variation.